# Row-wise interpolation in Simulink

Tags: matlab, block, interpolation, simulink

I have a 41x8 matrix which I want to use as a source in Simulink. The output of the source should be a row of size 8. The data needs to be interpolated between rows. for example:

there is a 41x1 monotonically increasing column vector that corresponds row-wise with the 41 rows of the first matrix,for example:

```
X=[0;        Z=[5   20;
   2.5;         10  26;
   5;           18  33;
   7.5;         27  41;
   10]          38  50]
```

The needs to be interpolated between columns (cubic spline interpolation if posible).
I hava an input that relates to a value in the X column vector.
Output of simulink model at different values of X for this example matrix:

```
X=[5]        Z=[18 33]

X=[6]        Z=[25.096 39.32]
```

The last Z values were obtained from cubic spline interpolation.

So far I've tried with a "MATLAB function" block in Simulink with the next code, and calling the matrix and vectors with a "From workspace" block. when i tryto run the simulation, an error ocurr and it says that the X and Z(i) vectors don't have the same dimensions in the function interp1()

```
function [I] = fcn(A,X, Z)

%A: traget value for column vector
%X: 41X1 column vector
%Z: 41x8 matrix

I=zeros(1,8); %Just creating the row filled with zeros

for i=1:8
     I(i)=interp1(X,Z(:,i),A,'spline'); % Building the row interpolating at 
                                          % the A value that corresponds 
                                          % with the X1 column vector
end        

%the I column vector is an interpolated row from Z

end
```

any idea on how to get it working?

PD: X is and Z values has to be read from the Matlab's Base Workspace.

Comment: What is `X1` in your code?  It isn't defined anywhere.  Also, what is `Z1`?

Comment: You should probably use the [nD Lookup table](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/ndlookuptable.html) instead of a MATLAB Function block.

Comment: rayryeng: I'm sorry, I just modify the questions since the function was miswritten. X1 and Z1 are now X and Z.

am304: the nDLookup table dosn't give columns as outputs